# Get the Records as per the given OrderId only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table with Primary key and auto incremented column lets say "HeaderFieldID".
Now i want to get the records as per the HeaderFieldID values.

Ex:

```
select * 
from tblHeaderField 
where HeaderFieldID in (2,1,3,4,6,5)
```

But,by default I am getting the records by HeaderFieldID asc order. But I want records as per the given HeaderFieldID's only.

Original Table

```
HeaderFieldID       HFName       DisplayName
      1              OrgName1      disp1
      2              OrgName2       disp2 
      3              OrgName3       disp3 
      4              OrgName4       disp4 
      5              OrgName5       disp5 
      6              OrgName6       disp6
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Are you looking to sort the results of your query?

Comment: Do you mean to order by the result in given order?

Comment: @user3017179 are you looking to sort by the order of the HeaderFieldID values specified by your IN clause?

Comment: yes Brandon you are correct

Comment: @user3017179: Accept the correct answer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my query.

```
SELECT * FROM tblHeaderField
WHERE HeaderFieldID in (5,6,2,1,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(CAST(HeaderFieldID AS VARCHAR), '5,6,2,1,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15')
```

Comment: It won't work. Try to use it with (12,3,1,2) and guess why I use `','+CAST(HeaderFieldID  as varchar(100))+','` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can order by IN, because you don't know order.
So first I would split data into rows from IN and then join it to your table.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, NR INT)

--Prodvide data to lookup
DECLARE @givenText VARCHAR(100) = '2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15'


-- Split requested string into rows and add unique number
;WITH xmlData (xmlData) AS (
    SELECT CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(@givenText, ',', '</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS xmlData
)
INSERT INTO @table (NR) 
SELECT x.value('.','INT') AS NR
FROM xmlData
CROSS APPLY xmlData.xmlData.nodes('//x') AS func(x)


--Join tables to get result
SELECT tHF.* 
FROM tblHeaderField AS tHF
INNER JOIN @table AS T
    ON T.NR = tHF.HeaderFieldID
ORDER BY T.ID
```

Comment: Yea your query works well... Thank you
Here you are created split function and you joined those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't clear where does this list come from (as a parameter of a stored procedure or hardcoded in the SQL statement?). Try this query:

```
select * 
from tblHeaderField 
where HeaderFieldID in (2,1,3,4,6,5)
ORDER BY 
   CHARINDEX(','+CAST(HeaderFieldID  as varchar(100))+','
              ,',2,1,3,4,6,5,')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32e23/16)</kbd>